MOSFET or IGBT for DC Motor
Hope you all have an idea. I've got a DC motor (universal, maybe?) with 2 brushes that was running on 120VAC with a bridge rectifier.  Says it's 13Amp. I'd like to PWM drive this motor from battery power.
I have a cheap PWM board, potentiometer, and the motor itself.
Question 1: If powered directly from battery voltage, should that be 10X 12V batteries for maximum results?
Question 2: If the answer to the above is yes, then is a Mosfet or IGBT a better choice?
I'd like to try to overdrive it, if possible (and it can be kept cool).  Is this approach correct?  Do I need around 100A capability?  First time designing something for power and would prefer to get it right the first time.  Thank you!

Just in regards to identification: is the motor magnetic at all? If so, it's probably PMDC. Which would explain the rectifier, as a universal wouldn't require such.  Or if you can peer inside the housing, a universal motor will have windings on the rotor and stator, while PMDC has stator magnets.

Why do you think you need 100A capacity when your motor is rated for 13A?

Give it a twirl; feel how hard it resists.  Short the motor leads, give it a twirl again, feel how hard it resists.  If it resists being spun when it's shorted, then it's a permanent-magnet motor, not universal.

It is a PMDC motor.  Close to 2hp, I'd say.  Very simple design, but it works.  My experience with steppers and servos gives me some insight.  Just making sure there isn't a gotcha hidden here somewhere.  Thank you all for ringing in!

Regarding circuit design, you have many hurdles before component choice matters:

Are you familiar with current-mode control?
Switching loop design, layout?
Switching circuits in general, theory of operation, etc.?
Protection (isolation, fusing, inrush)?

There are many things to get right the first time; done properly, this will be a lengthy project, but you can also learn a lot from it.
Current-mode control is a double bonus here, as it provides both protection for the switching circuit itself (the transistor cannot die of excess current because it is controlled to never exceed the current setpoint), as well as torque control (in a PMDC motor, torque is proportional to current, minus friction losses; in universal or series-wound, the relation is quadratic, but still a simple correspondence).  RPM control can then be done with a tach (sense motor, encoder, etc.), or EMF sensing (i.e. voltage regulation), to complete a basic ESC (electronic speed controller).
It's generally okay to overdrive a motor by several times, as long as it's momentary; excess heating and higher brush wear is the consequence.  As long as it doesn't overheat, and the shorter lifetime is acceptable, that's fine.  I suppose it also needs to not be overdriven so hard the magnets demagnetize (if applicable), but that's usually a higher margin than 2-3x.
Ten car batteries is no joke, and must be handled safely!
Ten Car Battery Presentation at Calgary Mini Maker Faire | ElectroBOOM | YouTube (still at 12:45 below)

Note that this Stack is engineering oriented, so I give an engineering-oriented answer.  If you just want building blocks to stick together, that falls under the "use of equipment" rule and is off-topic; in that case, I would suggest a more traditional conversation forum as a more appropriate venue.

You can try something like this as a first pass:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Definitely fuse the batteries. Not sure what your motor startup current is but a 25A fuse seems conservative as a first guess. Not to sure about your PWM controller, but make sure the PWM signal swings from 0V to at least 10V. When you start going under 10V on the PWM, the transistor is going to get hot. If your PWM controller only goes up to 5V, you are going to need level-shifting glue circuitry between the PWM controller and the transistor. Or, an appropriate gate driver.
D1 is probably not needed, but its a good idea anyway (cheap insurance for the transistor). Since the motor operates down to 100Hz to 120Hz, a slow switching frequency would be preferred from a transistor thermal standpoint. At 13A, it's not that important.
If you want to overdrive the motor, you are going to need more battery, not more current as you will be voltage limited. Take care cause 120VDC is already risky - worse than 120VAC from safety standpoint.
MOSFET or IGBT? Either will work for this. If you have the choice, go MOSFET - they're a little cheaper and a little faster. IGBT would be overkill to me. Again, whatever you choose, make sure your are driving them hard into saturation (full conduction). This transistor will likely be your weakest link. Over size it. Especially if you plan on overdriving the motor - Vds has to be at least the open-circuit voltage of the battery stack (a little more is better) and the current rating has to be at least stall current of the motor. Again more is better. A lot more will be necessary for overdriving the motor.

Note that a capacitor is needed between supply and ground, to close the loop with M1 and D1. Even if you aren't switching often (I would consider ~kHz minimal), the switching edge needs to be done quickly enough, and motor and wiring inductance add up quickly.

@TimWilliams I didn't include a bunch of things for brevity: the DP switch to turn it on and off, the decoupling cap for PWM controller and additional capacitance as you suggested. Obviously what I posted is a very crude motor controller, but it's super simple to get something going. If you were to design a real motor controller (w/ soft start, cycle-by-cycle current limit, OVP, SSP, OTP, ect) this is not how you do it.

What's the most important thing that's missing?

@MicroservicesOnDDD Depends on the non-existent reequipments. Want to elaborate?

Since @TimWilliams has shown how dangerous 12 car batteries in series is, I wanted you to elaborate on what you said, "If you were to design a real motor controller (w/ soft start, cycle-by-cycle current limit, OVP, SSP, OTP, etc) this is not how you do it" -- for the safety of whoever comes along. Please... (Also with interest on the "etc").

Gentlemen, this is all very helpful. As mentioned, my skillset isn't "geared" to power circuits, but I do understand everything you're saying, so, thank you!

@MicroservicesOnDDD I've provided the bare minimum to get the motor spinning. The additional features are needed for safety and performance that were omitted because this seems like a garage experiment. Soft-start: to mitigate nuance fuse tripping and mitigate surges. c-b-c i_limit: truncates the PWM pulse. OVP: overvoltage protection. SSP: short-circuit protection (protects MOSFET from shorted motor). OTP: Overtemperature protection. The "ect." would include PID or other feedback speed control, torque control, and communication and diagnostics to a host system.

Yes, this is a garage experiment, but also part of a feasibility study.  Goal to produce low end battery-driven device using off-the-shelf motor design.  My choice would be BLDC and typical driver.  This is what I was handed.  Little familiarity with larger DC motors doesn't help.  Out of the box BLDC, VFD, Servo, Stepper, no problem.  I do have working knowledge of electronics and enough parts to construct breadboard design.  Needed to start somewhere, MOSFET.  Thank you!

BTW, MOSFET, CANbus and Diag are part of the next REV, assuming the basic spin and speed control of this motor.

@Not_EE At minimum, I would suggest controlling the speed via current-mode and not voltage-mode because the torque produced is proportional to the current. It's very difficult to control the speed of a motor running open-loop by modulating it's voltage.

@MOSFET I agree with you.  An increase in voltage will only drive RPM's, which could be somewhat helpful, but more torque allows more work to be done.
